# how to page and query large data in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I need to query large amount of data from a database via C# and ADO.NET (`IDbDataReader` and `IDbCommand` API).
I've created a query like the follwing:

```
WITH v as 

(SELECT myFields, Datefield 

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Datefield ASC) AS CurrentRow 

FROM dbTable 

WHERE /**/ 

AND Datefield BETWEEN @pStart AND @pEnd 

// ... )


SELECT myFields, Datefield from v where CurrentRow 
BETWEEN @pRowStart AND @pRowEnd
```

From the results I have to use an C# API which will transform and generate new data,
thats why an SqlServer - only solution can't be used.

I want to query against the database with a pagesize of 10000 until there is no more data.
Something like

```
while (true)
{
  // ... execute reader
  if (reader.HasRows) 
     break;
}
```

will not work cause I have to use the IDbDataReader interface.

What can I do in my situation?

**EDIT + Solution**
I iterate over each block in a while loop and check `HasRows` property of the datareader, cause i can use the specialized type.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has added the OFFSET and NEXT clauses to the ORDER BY clause to simplify paging

Comment: Please let us know what version of SQL Server you are going to run this on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL Server 2012 you can use the OFFSET and FETCH clauses for simple and efficient paging, as shown in the [ORDER B](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)Y clause examples:

```
SELECT DepartmentID, Name, GroupName
FROM HumanResources.Department
ORDER BY DepartmentID ASC 
    OFFSET @StartingRowNumber - 1 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @RowCountPerPage ROWS ONLY;
```

On previous versions you can use a CTE and [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to calculate a number for each row and limit the results:

```
WITH OrdersRN AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate, OrderID) AS RowNum
      ,OrderID
      ,OrderDate
      ,CustomerID
      ,EmployeeID
    FROM dbo.Orders
)

SELECT * 
  FROM OrdersRN
  WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 
              AND @PageNum * @PageSize
  ORDER BY OrderDate ,OrderID;
```

Comment: I mark this as the answer because now I know how to do in 2012 version.